# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

Suddenly, early morning when I accessed our on-premise SharePoint site, I unable to access the site pages or every list listview pages. I checked into ULS Viewer and found the following issue.

> Application error when access /sandbox/Lists/Master
>   Process/AllItems.aspx, Error=Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton' to type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPPinnedSiteTile'.    at
>   T_SPPinnedSiteTile_TileColor_27.SetProperty(Object , Object )      at
>   System.Web.Util.FastPropertyAccessor.SetProperty(Object target, String
>   propName, Object val, Boolean inDesigner)      at
>   System.Web.UI.PropertyMapper.SetMappedPropertyValue(Object obj, String
>   mappedName, Object value, Boolean inDesigner)      at
>   System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.InitBoundProperty(Object obj,
>   BoundPropertyEntry entry, DataBindingCollection& dataBindings,
>   IAttributeAccessor& attributeAccessor)

I restart IIS serve with help of this [article](https://blog.sharepointrx.com/2016/04/13/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-webcontrols-splinkbutton/) and everything work back to normal.

I would like to know what is root cause for occur this issue? Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the reason?